# give access to magento admin panel " manage products" without editing

Tags: admin-panel, user-roles

we want to create a new user and role to access only "manage products section"

but we don't want to give access with edit the products information and attributes.

we just want to give access only to see the product and search the products.

please help me how to do it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not standard in Magento and so for a complete solution would required a lot of work.

One thing you could do is give the user the catalog permissions but then use a selection of admin events like before html and before save check the user and stop the action if the user is the one that you do not want to have access.